# NGINX - How to return 500 instead 408 response code?

Tags: nginx, http-status-codes

In NGINX is it possible to return, globally, a 500 response code instead returns  408? 
It's a strange request, I know. 
But from the client, that send requests to our Nginx, need to perform a retry if a request fails, and they are able only to intercept 5XX family errors at this time. Change the code is not possible in a quick time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set thus:

```
error_page 408 = @error_target;
location @error_target {
    return 500;
}
```